# How to reference a polymer component from inside an Angular.Dart component

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, angular-dart

I'm hoping someone can steer me on the right direction. I embedded a polymer component inside an Angular component. I would like to call a method from this polymer component from the angular component class. Is this possible, if yes how would you go about doing this? querySelector has not proven successful.
ang_comp.html:

```dart
<div id='ilovePolymer'>
    <bwu-grid id='polymerGrid'></bwu-grid>
</div>
```

ang_comp.dart:

```dart
@Component(selector: 'ang-comp', templateUrl:'ang_comp.html')
class AngularComp {
    ......//All the goodness
    querySelector('#ilovePolymer')  returns me null here.  
    querySelector('ang-comp').shadowRoot returns nothing  
    querySelector('bwu-grid') returns nothing.
```

I'm using Angular 1.0.0, Polymer 0.15.1+5

Comment: When dou you query the inner HTML? You can not do it in the constructor, use onShadowRoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you Ozan. That was a good suggestion, here is how I fixed it:

- Make sure you add `useShadowDom: true` to the component properties.
- The Angular component class implements `shadowRootAware`
- override `onShadowRoot` with the `@override` meta.

My example class:

> `@Component(selector: 'ang-comp', templateUrl:'ang_comp.html', useShadowRoot: true)` 
>      `class AngularComp implements ShadowRootAware {`
>      `... //some other stuff...`
>   `@override`
>   `onShadowRoot(ShadowRoot sr){`
>
> > `print(sr.querySelector('#polymerGrid') is bwu-grid); //This returns True! Yey!!`
> >
> > > `}`
> > >          `}`

By the way, your could also use `AttachAware` if you want to capture something during `attach`.

Comment: Component did not have the `useShadowDom: false` alternative from the beginning. When it was added it was decided to reuse the ShadowRootAware interface despite the contradicting name. Otherwise ShadowRootAware would have had to be renamed.

Comment: `onShadowRoot` is not working without `useShadowDom: true` and `ShadowRootAware` on AngularDart 1.1.0

Comment: ENDOH, 
I have it working without @override, and I make it a point to always define useShadowDom: true when creating new components. I wish the dart editor had new custom file templates, it'll make this much easier.